# How to Delete Edges Given Specific Vertex Labels?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Given the following directed graph, is there a way to delete all edges that contain a specified vertex label name. For instance, suppose the edge list below was read in. Any edge in that list with a vertex labeled by x would be deleted, along with the vertices on both sides of that edge. For example, in the edge list below, the graph would be generated for just the edges N4 -> N5, N6 -> N2, N6 -> N3,
N6 -> N4, N1 -> N8, N2 -> N8, N4 -> N8, N7 -> N8, N9 -> N7, N9 -> N8

```
edges = {N1 -> x, x -> N3, x -> x, N4 -> N5, N6 -> N2, N6 -> N3, 
  N6 -> N4, N1 -> N8, N2 -> N8, N4 -> N8, N7 -> N8, N9 -> N7, N9 -> N8}
g = Graph[edges, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`VertexDelete[g,v]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexDelete.html) to delete vertex $v$ and *all edges connected to $v$*.

```
VertexDelete[g, x]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, yes; of course!! ... Many thanks kglr!!